# Unable to send traffic to port 3015 in nginx

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to setup a nginx server on Debian to send traffic from my domain to the port 3015 where I`m running a Node Express app

This is my `/etc/nginx/sites-available$ sudo vim default`

```
server {

 listen 80;
 server_name transparentecontabilidade.com.br;
 location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:3015;
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
 }

}
```

When i run `etc/nginx/sites-available$ sudo systemctl restart nginx`

I get

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When I check errors `systemctl status nginx.service`

I get

```
listen() to 0.0.0.0:
Dec 25 15:26:17 wordpress-1-vm nginx[17448]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:
Dec 25 15:26:18 wordpress-1-vm nginx[17448]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:
Dec 25 15:26:18 wordpress-1-vm nginx[17448]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:
Dec 25 15:26:19 wordpress-1-vm nginx[17448]: nginx: [emerg] listen() to 0.0.0.0:
Dec 25 15:26:19 wordpress-1-vm nginx[17448]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind
Dec 25 15:26:19 wordpress-1-vm systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited
Dec 25 15:26:19 wordpress-1-vm systemd[1]: Failed to start A high performance we
Dec 25 15:26:19 wordpress-1-vm systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit entered failed st
Dec 25 15:26:19 wordpress-1-vm systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'ex
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: run this command to check if your configuration is right `sudo nginx -t`, the response should return , `nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok`, `nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`

Comment: @LuayAL-Assadi I receive exactly this
 nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: Is there any apache server running?, try to stop it then restart nginx

Comment: yes, but it's running another site of mine. Is there a way to run nginx and apache at the same time?

Comment: @FilipeFerminiano, could you please run command like `nststat -aonp | grep "3015"` and see if you get any results,. Basically we are checking if any service is running on that port currently or not.

Comment: You already have a process bound to the same port, you can use nginx as reverse proxy and make docker for nodejs app and another for your apahce service, I don't know if there are another solutions